# How to execute a command from a Typecript file?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

how to execute a command from a TS file ? (not from package.json)

**Here my files and my error :
src/devTools/server/tsconfig.json :**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target" : "ES2020",
    "module" : "CommonJS",
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "extends" : "../../../tsconfig.json", // the default config file of Create React App
}
```

**packages.json :**

```
"scripts": {
    "test:coverage": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register --project  src/devTools/server/tsconfig.json --transpile-only scripts/jest/runCoverage.ts",
  }
```

**scripts/jest/runCoverage.ts:**

```
const jestProcess = spawn('react-scripts', ['test'])
```

**Executed command:** npm run test:coverage

**Actual result:** error Command failed with exit code 1.

**Expected result:** none errors

Comment: Why not just call `react-scripts test` directly from the package.json script?

Comment: To create command parameters dynamically.